# What is the longhand of += assignment on this example in Java?

Tags: java, math, methods, operators, var

What is the longhand of `sum += value;` assignment operator in this java code example:

```
package com.company;

public class Temp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var i1 = 10;
        var i2 = 20;

        System.out.println("Result of two : " + totalSum(i1, i2));
        System.out.println("Result of multiple: " + totalSum(i1, i2, i1, i2));
    }

    public static double totalSum(int... values) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int value : values) {
            sum += value; // result = 60 (Correct output)
            /*
             * 
             * sum = value = value + value; // if this ! result is = 40 sum = value + value;
             * // if this ! result is = 40
             * 
             */
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT:**

```
Result of two : 30.0
Result of multiple: 60.0
```

Comment: sum = sum + value

Comment: `(a)` += `(b)` is always `a = a + (b)`.  This works for strings too: `str += "abc"` is `str = str + "abc"` .  The parenthesis around `(b)` is important, it really is there and don't get confused by the `+` order of operations.  `+=` is always evaluated last.

Comment: `sum += value;` is equal to `sum = sum + value;`

Comment: @MarsAtomic - Almost.  There is a cast in there as well:  `sum = (T)(sum + value);` where `T` is `int` in this case.  It makes no difference in this case, but it would if the type of `sum` was `byte`.

Comment: @StephenC Yeah, I saw that, but I got the impression that OP was more interested in the general operation of `+=` as opposed to the specifics of its application in this particular circumstance. I suppose it doesn't hurt to be more precise.